# I'm trying to create a column that identifies a telemetry detection by its season and year in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a telemetry dataset that I'm trying to merge with a food availability dataset that I have. To do so, I need to create a column in the telemetry data that identifies the detection by its defined season and the year of that season. For instance December 2021 - February 2022 would be Winter ('21).

[image: Sample Data]

```
Receiver Date       Time  TOA   TagID Type  Value Power timestamp           BATCH Beacon Serial. Release Relea…¹ River…²   RKM Locale GPS.C…³ X     Active INACT…⁴ Init.…⁵ Last.…⁶
  <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dttm>              <chr>  <int>   <int> <chr>     <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 3024     11/23/2021 15:5… 0.75… 39000 T     16.4  516   2021-11-23 15:54:42 MF B…   3024      NA ""           NA    184.  296. ""     N 32.1… W 08… Yes    ""      3/1/21  1/14/22
2 3024     11/23/2021 15:4… 0.24… 39100 T     16.4  56    2021-11-23 15:48:20 MF B…   3024      NA ""           NA    184.  296. ""     N 32.1… W 08… Yes    ""      3/1/21  1/14/22
3 3024     11/23/2021 15:4… 0.24… 39100 P     10.0  63    2021-11-23 15:48:30 MF B…   3024      NA ""           NA    184.  296. ""     N 32.1… W 08… Yes    ""      3/1/21  1/14/22
4 3024     11/23/2021 15:4… 0.24… 39100 T     16.4  159   2021-11-23 15:49:00 MF B…   3024      NA ""           NA    184.  296. ""     N 32.1… W 08… Yes    ""      3/1/21  1/14/22
5 3024     11/23/2021 15:4… 0.76… 39000 P     7.0   561   2021-11-23 15:49:12 MF B…   3024      NA ""           NA    184.  296. ""     N 32.1… W 08… Yes    ""      3/1/21  1/14/22
6 3024     11/23/2021 15:4… 0.24… 39100 P     12.0  472   2021-11-23 15:49:30 MF B…   3024      NA ""           NA    184.  296. ""     N 32.1… W 08… Yes    ""      3/1/21  1/14/22
```

I modified code that I found in another post, but cannot get it to work. I get the error message that ! 'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
date2season <- function(date) {
  season_start <- c("09-01-2021", "12-01-2021", "03-01-2022", "06-01-2022", "09-01-2022", "12-01-2022", "03-01-2023", "06-01-2023", "09-01-2023") # mmdd
  season_name <- c("FALL ('21)", "WINTER ('21)", "SPRING ('22)", "SUMMER ('22)", "FALL ('22)", "WINTER ('22)", "SPRING ('23)", "SUMMER ('23)", "FALL ('23)")
  mmddyyy <- format(date, "%m%d%Y")
  season_name[findInterval(mmddyyy, season_start)] ##
}

dat2 <- dat
dat2 <- dat2[order(as.Date(dat2$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")),] # sorting by date, so that manual data now is with the passive data


class(dat2$Date) # checking that Date was converted to Date format
dat2 <- dat %>% mutate(sxy = date2season(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")))

error:
> dat2 <- dat %>% mutate(sxy = date2season(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")))
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `sxy = date2season(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))`.
Caused by error in `findInterval()`:
! 'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs
Backtrace:
 1. dat %>% mutate(sxy = date2season(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")))
 7. global date2season(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
 8. base::findInterval(mmddyyy, season_start)
 9. base::stop("'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, callmechris! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: This is certainly an improvement, but do you see how we can't use the _output_ of your frame for sample data? The first problem is that several of the (`chr`) fields are truncated, the second (perhaps less obvious) is that in order to copy from a question on Stack to our own instance of R, we have to parse it as a table, and embedded spaces (i.e., in your `timestamp` column) make that less simple. We can do it, but it is far better to have unambiguous data. Please use `dput(head(dat))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of inconsistencies/problems with your `date2season` function:

1. `season_start` is in `"%m-%d-%Y"`, whereas you format the `date` argument as `"%m%d%Y"` (no dashes); this is really not the biggest problem, so we'll ignore it for now.
2. Your interval-testing is doing so on *strings*, not on dates, so it will be far slower and less efficient. Again, this is not causing your error, but it's really not what should be done.
3. Because you have `"09"-`, `"12"-`, `"03"-`, ... in your `season_start`, no matter what else, *that* is decreasing (even as strings). `findInterval` requires its `vec=` (second) argument to be

   ```
   vec: numeric, sorted (weakly) increasingly, ...
   ```

I suggest you bring your data and seasons into a proper `Date`-class, something like:

```r
date2season <- function(date) {
  stopifnot(inherits(date, "Date"))
  season_start <- c("09-01-2021", "12-01-2021", "03-01-2022", "06-01-2022", "09-01-2022", "12-01-2022", "03-01-2023", "06-01-2023", "09-01-2023") # mmdd
  season_start <- as.Date(season_start, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
  season_name <- c("FALL ('21)", "WINTER ('21)", "SPRING ('22)", "SUMMER ('22)", "FALL ('22)", "WINTER ('22)", "SPRING ('23)", "SUMMER ('23)", "FALL ('23)")
  season_name[findInterval(date, season_start)] ##
}
```

Quick test:

```r
dates <- as.Date(c("10-01-2021", "12-15-2021", "03-10-2022", "06-22-2022"), format="%m-%d-%Y")
dates
# [1] "2021-10-01" "2021-12-15" "2022-03-10" "2022-06-22"
date2season(dates)
# [1] "FALL ('21)"   "WINTER ('21)" "SPRING ('22)" "SUMMER ('22)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot express how much I appreciate the help. I apologize for the poorly formatted question.

Comment: @callmechris consider upvoting and marking r2evans's answer correct! :-) They appear to have put a decent amount of work into it, and it's one way of showing your appreciation and letting other users know your problem has been solved

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Will do, although it will not allow me to upvote on anything yet.

Comment: @callmechris thanks, I appreciate it, every forum has its own rules, etiquette, and expectations. Yes, you don't get the "privilege" to upvote for a bit, but you get a couple points when you "accept" an answer, and more when others upvote your questions/answers. Eventually you'll be able to (\*gasp\*) comment on somebody else's question :-D